# Alter JavaScript Object to be more Numerical

Tags: javascript

I'd like to change this JS object.  I currently have:

```
for(var i = 0; i < destination_categories_selected.length; i++)
 {
  destination_categories_obj[i] = { 
                                   "category" : $(destination_categories_selected[i]).data("dkDropdownValue")
                                  }
 }
```

Which outputs and object that looks like

```
[0] => "category" : 1,
[1] => "category" : 2,
[2] => "category" : 3
```

Can I make this so that category is completely removed to something like:

```
[0] => 1,
[1] => 2,
[2] => 3
```

Comment: Just remove the object literal, replacing it by the property value?

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your question correctly then just assign the value directly to the element of `destination_categories_obj` in question, rather than assigning an object to it:

```
for(var i = 0; i < destination_categories_selected.length; i++) {
    destination_categories_obj[i] = $(destination_categories_selected[i]).data("dkDropdownValue");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(var i = 0; i < destination_categories_selected.length; i++)
 {
  destination_categories_obj[i] = 
       $(destination_categories_selected[i]).data("dkDropdownValue");

 }
```